# How to get Y coordinate of element that drag is over it

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have table

and I want to implement **drag and drop** row in order to **sort** it

for that i need to know **top offset** of element that drag is **over** it .

like below image

I want know this **distance**

[image]

```html
<table>
  <tr @dragover="dragOver">
     ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my js

```js
function dragOver(e){
  const distance_from_window_top= /// i dont know which codes come here
}
```

so How can I calculate it ?

Comment: el.getBoundingClientRect().top